# How often fluent-bit AWS filter calling AWS metadata API endpoint for EC2 instance tags

Tags: logging, amazon-ec2, newrelic, fluent-bit

I need to understand how often [fluent-bit aws filter plugin](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/filters/aws-metadata) calls the AWS EC2 metadata API endpoint for EC2 instance tags if I'm using it to enrich log records from the [tail input plugin](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/inputs/tail) before those logs will be sent to the NewRelic with [nrlogs output plugin](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/outputs/new-relic).

Does it make an API call for every log record or on some time interval or every time input plugin flushes its buffer? Or does it make a single call on the fluent-bit process startup? Can't get that form the official docs.

I looked through [this file](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/blob/master/plugins/filter_aws/aws.c) and found [this line](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/blob/master/plugins/filter_aws/aws.c#L194) and also [this](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-bit/blob/master/plugins/filter_aws/aws.c#L577), so seems like it looks for tags every time fluent-bit input plugin flushes its buffer, which is default as 5 sec, but I'm not sure if I'm getting it correct.